# Is /... or /abc/... a valid unix path?

Tags: unix, path

I read somewhere that `/...` is a valid unix path. But when I try it out, I get an error.

```
$ cd /...
-bash: cd: /...: No such file or directory
```

Can someone clarify?

Comment: you can try `/..` i read somewhere is a valid path, without error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid path, but *"no such file or directory"* with that path exists - this doesn't make the path inherently invalid.

For instance, it is trivial to create such directory and then change to it (although using such a name should generally be discouraged):

```
mkdir ...
cd ...
```

Perhaps you were thinking of [`.` and `..`](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/absolute-and-relative-paths-256350/)?

---

Now, is `/..` a valid path? Yes, it is a valid *absolute* path (because it starts with `/`).

In this case, `/`, `/.` and `/..` all refer to the same thing - the root directory. (The parent of a root directory is itself.)

```
ls -ldi / /. /..
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking of relative paths and ignored the fact that it can be a filename. Thanks :)

Comment: Right. `.` and `..` are special. `...` is just another name.